# JS: создание битового массива

Tags: javascript

Допустим, есть массив нескольких байт. Как из них сделать битовый массив?

Comment: @AVM, Что вы подразумеваете под битовым массивом и зачем он вам?

Comment: Вы не ответили на мой вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Можно выделять биты с помощью битовых масок:

```js
let input = [0x00, 0x0F, 0xF0, 0xFF];
// Построим маски
let arr8 = new Array(8).fill(0);
let masks = arr8.map((_, i) => 1 << i);
// bool биты
let boolbits = input.map(byte => masks.map(mask => !!(byte & mask)));
// char биты
let charbits = input.map(byte => masks.map(mask => byte & mask?'1':'0'));
// int биты
let intbits = input.map(byte => masks.map(mask => byte & mask ? 1 : 0).reverse()).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), [])

console.log(charbits.map(byte => byte.reverse().join('')));
console.log(JSON.stringify(intbits))
```

Можно с помощью сдвига:

```js
let input = [0x00, 0x0F, 0xF0, 0xFF];

let bits = input.map(byte => {
  let bits = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    bits.unshift(byte & 1); // В этот раз изменим порядок, младший бит будет последним
    byte = byte >> 1;
  }
  return bits;
});

// Можно собрать все биты в один массив
let result = bits.reduce((c, a) => c.concat(a));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Ну понятно, встроенных специфических функций там нет, надо вручную (((